# execute a Kermeta file from a Java program

Tags: java, transformation

I developed a transformation that generates a Kermeta XMI file.

My problem is that I would run this transformation (.kmt file) in the background, that is to say from a Java program.

I tried a lot of code but always without result.

Someone can help me?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a kermeta program depends on the version of Kermeta and about its execution context.
With Kermeta 2, the kmt code is compiled into scala. This scala code can be directly called from java thanks to scala compatibility with java.
You first need to declare at least one main operation in order to generate the appropriate initialization operation.
Let's say you have a method "transformFooToBar" in a class "org::example::FooToBar" in your kermeta code.
Declare it as a main entry point using the tags

```
@mainClass "org::example::FooToBar"
@mainOperation "transformFooToBar"
```

This main operation must have only string parameters.
This will generate an utility scala class org.example.MainRunner which contains useful initialization methods and a main operation that you can call from the command line.

- Case 1/ With Kermeta 2 code **called from an eclipse plugin**:
  This is the simpliest case, call the method `org.example.MainRunner.init4eclipse()`

before any other call. Then call your main method `org.example.KerRichFactory.createFooToBar.transformFooToBar()`

You can call any other classes or methods (ie. even with parameters that aren't String)

This is quite convinient for building tool for eclipse based on kermeta transformation.

- Case 2/ Kermeta 2 code **called from a standard java application** (ie. not running in an eclipse plugin)
  The initialiation method is then `org.example.MainRunner.init()`

**Common trap for case 2**: many transformations that run as standalone  still need to manipulate models using eclipse uri scheme in their internal refencing system. Ie. platform:/plugin/... , platform:/resource/..., pathmap:/... , or even more complex uri mapping (typically using custom protocols ) (you can check that easily in by looking in the xmi files as text)
In that case, since Eclipse platform isn't running to provide the search mechanism, you need to provide manually the equivalent URI mapping to map these URI to your local system URI (Ie. to file:/... or jar:file:/ URIs)
One possibility is to use an urimap.properties file that provide such mapping. By default when running a kermeta program in eclipse, an urimap.properties is generated for the current eclipse configuration.
When deploying a kermeta program to another computer, or using a custom deployment packaging, you will have to provide/compute an equivalent file for the target computer.

For convinience, you can set the location of this urimap.properties files thanks to the system propery "urimap.file.location"

Comment: Hello Didier, thank  you so much for the answer  It was very helpful.
now i can run kermeta transformation from java